# Empty Trash Item in Use

Tags: macos, catalina, trash

I recently upgraded my 2012 MacMini to Catalina. It was a bit of a nightmare as the internal drive wasn’t formatted to APFS. I imaged the drive and did a Time Machine backup then booted from the imaged drive, formatted the internal to APFS. Ran the Catalina installer file from the imaged drive and installed it on the internal drive. I then transferred all the data from the TM backup. It all seemed to work fine and I’m up and running.

The only issue is that It moved/copied a couple extra versions of user folders. I went in and cleaned/deleted them from the Users & Groups Sys Pref. When I go to empty the trash, it says the following for apparently 5 items that won’t delete.

> The operation can’t be completed because the item “Data” is in use.
>   The operation can’t be completed because the item “com.apple.mail” is in use.
>   The operation can’t be completed because the item “Containers” is in use.
>   The operation can’t be completed because the item “Library” is in use.
>   The operation can’t be completed because the item “acct name” is in use.

(account name redacted)

I have tried rebooting the computer several times and tried the force empty all to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar problem. My locked files were located in the trash bin of my Time Machine disk.

In the end, I forced the deletion by using the `rm` command.

1. Open your Trash window to actually see the locked files.
2. Open a terminal session to type the following (have your password ready)

   ```
   sudo rm -R [drag and drop the locked files here]
   ```
3. Type your password when asked to do so.

Source: 
https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-empty-trash-on-mac-3682422/

---

On a side note, I found something interesting: I noticed that the folder I wanted to remove showed as "Username's Macbook" in the Finder window, but in the terminal, it was like "Username/1/2/4/s Macbook".

Too bad I didn't write it down. So I wonder if there was something wrong with the character encoding.